# C# ASP.NET: How to automatically decode my bearer token for each method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have a Web API that uses bearer tokens for authentication and authorization. The presence of a token signifies that the user is authenticated; the claims within that token specify the authorizations the user has.

I wrote an OAuth class that queries the database upon user login to determine the user's permissions. All of this works fine.

Now, for each method in each controller, I need to extract information from the bearer token's claims. What I have done now is to define a class that contains the entities I need from the token and write a static method to take a `User` object from within a controller method and produce an instance of my class containing the token data:

```
// Bearer token class
class TokenData 
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string UserTag { get; set; }
    // ... more properties as needed
}

// Method to get bearer token data from user object
internal static TokenData getTokenDataFromUserPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal p)
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)p.Identity;
    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;

    var enumerable = claims as Claim[] ?? claims.ToArray();
    var claimTypes = from x in enumerable select x.Type;

    var types = claimTypes as string[] ?? claimTypes.ToArray();
    if (!types.Contains("userId")) return null; // if a token was given but it has no UserID it's not valid.

    var claimsByType = enumerable.ToDictionary(x => x.Type, x => x.Value);

    TokenData td = new TokenData
    {
        UserId = claimsByType["userId"],
        GroupId = types.Contains("groupId") ? int.Parse(claimsByType["groupId"]) : 0,
        UserTag = types.Contains("userTag") ? claimsByType["userTag"]) : null,
        // more properies as needed
    };
    return td;
}

// A controller method that uses the claims
public HttpResponseMessage DoSomething() 
{
    TokenData td = getTokenDataFromUserPrincipal(User);
    // Now I can access the token data in the td variable.
    return Request.CreateResponse(td.UserId);
}
```

Ok, so this all works perfectly. The thing I'm looking for though is if there's a way to *automate* pulling the claims from the User object whenever a controller method is invoked.

The Web API architecture already basically does this with the `User` object itself - it contains any information that is part of the request related to the user. (Similar to the `Request` object, which contains all of the HTTP request data.)

What I'd like to be able to do is, instead of calling `getTokenDataFromUserPrincipal` at the start of each controller, to instead just have a static variable available similar to how Web API does it - e.g. `TokenData`. For example:

```
// A controller method that uses the claims and doesn't have to explicitly retrieve them.
public HttpResponseMessage DoSomething() 
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(TokenData.UserId);
}
```

I do know how to use attributes - I actually wrote custom attributes which pull the same token data and use it to determine if a user can access a certain class of function - so for example I can just include `[MinimumUserLevel(2)]` in front of my controller methods. But having to add an attribute to each method simply moves the problem outside of the method.

To sum: Is it possible to have another static variable, scoped at the request level, that user code can populate per request without having to copy code to the beginning of each controller method?

Ideally, there would be a way to insert a function in the pipeline, so that prior to the controller method being run, I can run the code to get the token data from the principal, so it will be ready when the controller method runs. (Note that the method to pull token data simply returns null if the data doesn't exist - this is the expected behavior for this static variable in the instance of a call with no token.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be simpler than I was making it: define a subclass of `ApiController`.

So I simply wrote a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController 
{
    // Makes token data available to any method on a class deriving from MyApiController
    public TokenData Token { get; set; }

    // Override constructor - parse token whenever instance is created
    public MyApiController() 
    {
        // Extract the token data from the User variable (User is pulled in from the base ApiController)
        Token = getTokenDataFromUserPrincipal(User);
    }

    private static TokenData getTokenDataFromUserPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal p)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I have all of my controllers derive from `MyApiController` rather than from `ApiController`. From that point, I'm able to access the `Token` variable in any controller's logic, which will contain the parsed token data.

Answer (score 0):

You can either manually verify the jwt token. Or add the JwtBearerAuthentication to the Owin stack.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/siacomuzzi/4fa48e32932473348fd2) is one of the found samples. This would parse the token for each request and set the User properties of each request.

You would have to set it up for the secret you were using when you created the jwt token.

The provided sample validates and converts the JWT token to a ClaimsIdentity which is set on each request and is accessible through the `User.Identity` property within each controller. No custom code is necessary for that.

And since this package is provided by Microsoft, it might be better then some self made JWT parser.

`(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("userId")?.Value` to access your user ID.

You could also extend the IIdentity with the following code.

```
public static class IIdentityExtensions
{
    public static string UserId(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        return identity.GetClaimValue("userId");
    }

    public static string GetClaimValue(this IIdentity identity, string claimType)
    {
        return identity
            .AsClaimsIdentity()
            .Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == claimType)?.Value;
    }

    private static ClaimsIdentity AsClaimsIdentity(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (!(identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false))
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("User not logged-in");

        return identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    }
}
```

And then accessing the user id like `User.Identity.UserId()`

Comment: This misses the point of the question. The token is already able to be decoded with my custom method, but I would like to know if I can somehow *extend* the environment so that another object is automatically available to me within each web request method. For example, any time you are in a controller method, you have access to `Request` without having to qualify it at all. I'd like to be able to extend ASP.NET somehow so that the method I wrote above executes for any controller method and presents its results in static values, without having to do the manual call out to the extractor.